# metatag for custom path

Tags: meta-tags

I need to set some info for SEO and sharing. I know that I can use the Metatag module for nodes, views and front page. In fact, I use it for them. Now I need to set some information for custom paths (create via `hook_menu()`). I know that I can use something like `drupal_add_html_head($metatag_description_custom, 'description')`, but I want to give to my client the possibility to change this and others tags (e.g. og:description, og:image).

Is there a way (or a module) to do this without create and change a custom module's code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [Path metatags](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_metatags) module

> Path metatags module helps you to create metatags for any page with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!